# Rotating/moving one uiview and moving others at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, move

This is my first question here and I'm a newby to iOS programming.

I've searched all over the web, with many tips coming from stackoverflow. Ive searched through the Xcode help and watched video's etc, but I still can't seem to get this to work.

I have one view with about 6 different UIViews. One of the UIViews is an arrow image that is above another UIView of a vertical panel. The arrow image is receiving a touch, which then triggers two methods

One method moves the panel and the arrow to the right. The other method rotates the arrow along with the move.

I have tried `CATransform3DMakeRotation`, `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and `CATransform3DMakeRotation`, but I cannot get the arrow to rotate with the move of the arrow and the move of the panel.

The best I have been able to achieve was with the `CATransform3DMakeRotation`, but this just flips the arrow, and doesn't animate the rotation.

The others will rotate the arrow, but will not allow the move of the panel.

Here is my code to rotate the arrow.
As you can see. Lots of commented out items that I've tried.

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGRect bugRect = [[[RightArrow layer] presentationLayer] frame];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(bugRect, touchLocation)) {
        [self RotateArrowOFF];
        [self MovePanels];
        NSLog(@"Arrow tapped!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Arrow not tapped.");
        return;
    }

}

-(IBAction)MoveLeftColorPanel
{
    NSLog(@"Right Arrow Center %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(RightArrow.center));

}
- (void)MovePanels
{


    if (_PanelsAreOffScreen == NO) { 

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
            RightPanel.center = CGPointMake(1065, 384);
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Animation 1 complete");
                             _PanelsAreMoving = YES;

                         }];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            LeftPanel.center = CGPointMake(-50, 384);
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Animation 2 complete");
                             _PanelsAreMoving = YES;

                         }];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            RightArrow.center = CGPointMake(1010, 82);
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Animation 3 complete");
                             _PanelsAreMoving = YES;

                         }];

        _PanelsAreOffScreen = YES;
    }
    else { 
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            RightPanel.center = CGPointMake(914, 384);
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Animation 5 complete");
                         }];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            LeftPanel.center = CGPointMake(108, 384);
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Animation 6 complete");
                         }];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
            RightArrow.center = CGPointMake(836, 82);
        }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             NSLog(@"Animation 7 complete");
                         }];

        _PanelsAreOffScreen = NO;
    }

}

- (void)RotateArrowOFF//:(CGRect)rect
{

    RightArrow.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.06, 0.5);

    if (_PanelsAreOffScreen == NO)
    {
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
        CATransform3D RotateArrow = RightArrow.layer.transform;
        RotateArrow = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        RightArrow.layer.transform = RotateArrow;
    }
    else
    {
        [CATransaction begin];
        [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

        CATransform3D RotateArrow = RightArrow.layer.transform;
        RotateArrow = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f);
        RightArrow.layer.transform = RotateArrow;

        [CATransaction commit];
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>     RightArrow.layer.transform = RotateArrow;
> ```

So your question is, why isn't there any animation happening here? The problem is that RightArrow is a UIView, so `RightArrow.layer` is its "underlying layer". You cannot implicitly animate the underlying layer of a view merely by assigning to a property of it. You must either use UIView animation (using the view's `transform` property) or else you must use Core Animation directly (CABasicAnimation).

Here's an example (from my book):

```
[CATransaction setDisableActions:YES];
v.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(v.layer.transform, M_PI/4.0, 0, 0, 1);
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
anim.duration = 0.8;
[v.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Awesome answer. Shortly after I posted my original Question. I found the Core Animation, used it and it worked, just like you said. I didn't really understand why, until you answered... Thanks.

Comment: You might want to read my book's chapter on animation: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html